# Compare dict value with other dict

Tags: python, dictionary, compare

I have an dict which contains treshold value and a dict with some acutal amounts. *Which not always contain all keys from the minimum treshold dict.*

Now i would like to compare the actualAmounts with the minimumTresholds, this is what i come up with, but that does not work

```
minimumTresholds = {'key 1' : 100, 'key 2' : 100, 'key 3' : 1000}
actualAmounts = {'key 1' : 237, 'key 3' : 903}

for k, v in actualAmounts.items():
    if actualAmounts[k] == minimumTresholds[k] and actualAmounts[v] < minimumTresholds[v]:
         print(actualAmounts[k])
```

The expected result would be:

```
'key 3'
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem in your logic.

`if actualAmounts[k] == minimumTresholds[k] and actualAmounts[v] < minimumTresholds[v]:`
You are doing a lookup in a dict with a value.
actualAmounts[v] will trow an error since the value is not a key in that dict.

you can check if the key is present in the the other dict using the `in` keyword:

```
for key, value in actualAmounts.items():
    if key in minimumTresholds and value < minimumTresholds[key]:
        print(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
minimumTresholds = {'key 1' : 100, 'key 2' : 100, 'key 3' : 1000}
actualAmounts = {'key 1' : 237, 'key 3' : 903}

for i in actualAmounts.keys() :
    if i in minimumTresholds.keys() and actualAmounts[i] < minimumTresholds[i] :
        print(i)
```